# Reuse the write stream without ending it and declaring new stream over and over again

Tags: node.js, stream, child-process

this function is inside another function which sets the *wStream* write stream
to a file where the wStream runs once successfully.

running this however

```
fs.watch(fname, function watcher (evt, fname) {


        if (evt === 'change') {
            wStream.write("File " + fname + " changed\n");

        } else if (evt === 'rename') {
            wStream.write("File " + orig + " renamed\n");

        }
```

yields this error

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:167:12)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:214:5)
```

How can I keep reusing it without ending this stream?

**UPDATE**
As pointed out in the comments section, there is a process ending this stream explicitly.

I am running a child_process.spawn method on it like

```
SomeSpawn.stdout.pipe( wStream );
```

Why and how is it responsible for closing this stream? And how can I stop it from closing it explicitly?
something like `{end:false}`?

Comment: You're probably calling `end()` on the writable stream, directly or indirectly. Could you please post more of you code, like the parts where you manipulate `wStream`?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros interesting. the other thing touching wStream is SomeSpawn.stdout.pipe( wStream ); which is a child_process.spawn method. how does that close the wStream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) returns a ChildProcess object. This process has its own [`stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout), which it's a ReadableStream. A ReadableStream, when piped to a writable stream, calls `end()` on this writable stream when it finishes reading.

If you don't want to let the readable stream close the destination stream automatically in the end, just pass to `pipe` the option `{ end: false }`, like:

```
SomeSpawn.stdout.pipe( wStream, { end: false } );
```

In this case, you'll have to close it manually sometime in the future.

Comment: how can I stop it from closing it explicitly?

Comment: would child.disconnect() like SomeSpawn.disconnect() work in case of manual close?

Comment: Since the code is async, im not sure when to do child.disconnect() and where to perform try catch and do catch the error gracefully